# vba code works on one sheet but not the second worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a find function that will find the entered requisition number, then places information into cells over from the cell that is being searched. I only changed the sheet name and the range from the original formula. Nothing else is different. I get an error

> '1004' "Unable to get the Activate property of the Range class"

at the .activate

I was able to get the code working by inserting the activate before

```
    dim ReqNumber
```

That worked, however now it's telling me object required for the search method beginning at.

```
    set cF= .Find
```

That's giving me problems. I am not quite sure what is wrong now.

```
 Dim ReqNumber As Variant
ReqNumber = InputBox("Please Enter Requisition Number", "Information")

Dim FirstAddress As String, cF As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(" MthruF Schedule").Range("A:A")
    .Cells(1, 1).Activate
    'First, define properly the Find method
    Set cF = .Find(What:=ReqNumber, _
                after:=ActiveCell, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                SearchFormat:=False)

    'If there is a result, keep looking with FindNext method
    If Not cF Is Nothing Then
        FirstAddress = cF.Address
        Do
            cF.Offset(0, 8).Value = ReqNumber
            cF.Offset(0, 9).Value = EmpInfo.FirstName.Value & " " & EmpInfo.LastName.Value
            cF.Offset(0, 10).Value = EmpInfo.ComboBox3.Value & "/" & EmpInfo.ComboBox20.Value & "/" & EmpInfo.YearCmb.Value
            cF.Offset(0, 11).Value = EmpInfo.AgencyBox.Value
            Set cF = .FindNext(cF)
        'Look until you find again the first result
        Loop While Not cF Is Nothing And cF.Address <> FirstAddress
    End If
End With
```

Comment: Is `MthruF Schedule` the active sheet when you try and activate `A1` on that sheet, and as @Denyo said - does it really have a space at the front?

Answer (score 0):

I *think* it's because you've got the wrong sheet selected when you run the code.
This code fails if you're not on the correct sheet:

```
Worksheets("MthruF Schedule").range("A1").activate
```

To perform the search no matter what sheet you're on remove the `.Cells(1,1).Activate` line - you don't need to select or activate a cell to work with it.

In the `FIND` replace `ActiveCell` with `.Cells(1,1)`.

With these changes  your `FIND` will always look in column A of the `MthruF Schedule` starting at cell `A1` no matter what sheet you're on.

**Edit:**
As you're not changing the value you find there's no need to have the `Not cF Is Nothing` in your loop.  The `FIND` will always find a value unless you're changing it - so just check that `cF.Address <> FirstAddress`.

Comment: No this isn't working. I am taking information from a userform and putting it in multiple locations using the requisition number as the locator. This will then place the information into multiple sheets. It doesn't matter what I do the error is the same.

Comment: The last bit of your code is taking info from the `EmpInfo` form, but the first bit is exclusively looking for the `ReqNumber` on the `MthruF Schedule` as long as it's the activesheet.  If another sheet is selected then `.Cells(1,1).Activate` throws a `1004: Activate method of Range class failed` error every time.